# ngTagsInput is not supporting input type as email

Tags: ng-tags-input

I am using **ngTagsInput** component, which is not supporting type as email,
which means even if I entered text value it's not showing error.

can anyone help on this.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" type="email"></tags-input>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

The email type is mainly to get the right keyboard on mobile.
Use the on-tag-adding to return true or false depending on the type of input.
Or solve it manually by checking on user input.

```
<tags-input on-tag-adding="returnsTrueIfEmail($tag)"></tags-input>
```

http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api